# Installing wine in debian

Tags: debian, wine

i'm totally new to debian and i've been trying to install wine.This is what i did...

```
root@sutta:/home/sutta# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
Welcome to the Wine Team PPA.  Here you can get the latest available Wine   betas for every supported version of Ubuntu.  This PPA is managed by Scott  Ritchie and Maarten Lankhorst.
More info: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring   --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.je9yp6CIpu --trustdb-name /etc/apt//trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-squeeze-stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-automatic.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d//debian-archive-wheezy-stable.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80/ --recv 883E8688397576B6C509DF495A9A06AEF9CB8DB0
gpg: requesting key F9CB8DB0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key F9CB8DB0: "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Wine Team" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
root@sutta:/home/sutta# sudo apt-get update
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wheezy Release.gpg                     
Could not resolve 'proxy.falcot.com'
Err http://ftp.cn.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg                     
Could not resolve 'proxy.falcot.com'
Reading package lists... Done      
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.cn.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'proxy.falcot.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/wheezy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'proxy.falcot.com'

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@sutta:/home/sutta# sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine1.7
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.7'
```

My steps would probably be wrong.
Can some one tell me the right steps to download wine in debian ?
Please help me out..!

Comment: This is not a computer programming question.

Comment: ok so i wont find an answer here ehh ??

Comment: Probably not since this site is for specific computer programming questions and you are asking how to install something on your machine.

Comment: the proper forum might be [su].

Comment: and why do you add Ubuntu PPAs if you are running Debian? btw, `wine` is already packaged for Debian.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a 32-bit architecture in your repository:

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 | sudo apt-get update
```

Now:

```
sudo apt-get install wine.
```

The sintax of wine is:

`wine <runnable.exe>`

I home my answer is enough

Answer (score 1):

try install from the GUI software manager. i.e. gnome-software