# 64bit debian and 32bit Wine

Tags: debian, x86-64, wine, debian-jessie

I'm trying to install 32bit Wine on 64bit Debian Jessie. I've tried suggestions from:
[Can't build 32bit Wine on 64bit linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780319/cant-build-32bit-wine-on-64bit-linux)
and:
[Installing wine in debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276387/installing-wine-in-debian)

but all the time I got:

```
apt-get install libcapi20-dev:i386 libcups2:i386 libdbus-1-3:i386 libfontconfig:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libncurses5:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libsane:i386 libxcomposite1:i386 libxcursor1:i386 libxi6:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386
Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1:i386' instead of 'libfontconfig:i386'
Package libgphoto2-2:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    is only available from another source
    However the following packages replace it:
      libgphoto2-l10n

    Package libgnutls26:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    is only available from another source

    E: Package 'libgnutls26:i386' has no installation candidate
    E: Package 'libgphoto2-2:i386' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried to build wine 1.4 from source and after:

```
./configure --disable-win64
```

I've received that errors occured.

Could you please suggest me what should I try more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `libgphoto2-2:i386` is not available on debian jessie , it is [only available on debian wheezy](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libgphoto2-2) and the [`libgphoto2-l10n`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/libgphoto2-l10n) replace it.

the [`libgnutls26:i386`](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgnutls26) is only available for debian Wheezy and Sid , it can not be installed on debian jessie.

The `wine` program is available on [jessie backports](https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/wine) with multiarch support (`Architecture=All`)

Edit your `sources.list`, open the terminal and run the following:

```
sudo apt edit-sources
```

Add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
```

Save your file then run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
```

Install the 32 bit version of wine:

```
sudo apt install -t jessie-backports wine32
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped and solved my problem! Does the additional architecture (i386) may cause any problems with other packages? I mean during installation (in future) of new packages should I add -amd64 or it will be default anyway?

Comment: Adding multiarch is safe there is some info from debian https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve what you want after executing the following two steps first:

**1) Update your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and then run `apt-get update`**

I suggest the following for the `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Don't forget to run `apt-get update` after updating the list

**2) Install 32bit architecture on your computer, run `apt-get update` and `reboot`**

```
dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install -f && reboot
```

After you finish the two steps above, try to install/run `wine` 32bit again. I hope this helps!

**Edit: for most people, the best way to install `wine` is to install the package `playonlinux`**. The package `playonlinux` installs `wine` alongside with an useful `gui` interface to run things on it -- `playonlinux` was originally designed for games (hence the name), but it can "run" all kinds of software. It makes using `wine` much easier. To install `playonlinux`, I suggest:

`apt-get update && apt-get -y install playonlinux`

After that succeeds, look for `playonlinux` on your computer (normally it is grouped in the "games" category), open the program and wait while it updates its database (it does it automatically, look on the program window bottom part for the text "Refreshing PlayOnLinux" and a status bar; when the status bar reaches the end, it will disappear and "PlayOnLinux" will be fully updated). After that it should be ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply. I've done what you suggested, but there are still some problems, this time with X-server:

```
configure: error: X 32-bit development files not found. Wine will be built
without X support, which probably isn't what you want. You will need
to install 32-bit development packages of Xlib/Xfree86 at the very least.
```

I have some nvidia drivers previously installed, thus I am afraid about restoring drivers back to Nouveau.

Comment: I updated my answer, see if that works for you. Also, I believe that you posted this answer as a comment to my answer -- on Stack Overflow, you would prefer to comment on my answer directly (so that I will be notified of that), rather than commenting in a different answer; answers should be posted when they answer the question asked, thus you might consider to delete this answer and comment directly on my (or other people's ) answer(s).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize about such a package. I've managed to install wine thanks to this, does the package you recommended (playonlinux) use the same dependencies?

Comment: Installing `playonlinux` takes care of all needed dependencies (it has the same dependencies as wine, and adds some of its own). Mag, if my answer solved your problem, please select it as the "right" answer, so that it can help others as well. Good luck!